# How can I add background image to an html section?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web-development so please bear with me.
I would like to add a background image to this section:
[image]

Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: I did make some research. But, there was no answer to how you add a background image to a specific section. sorry

Comment: Clearly you have not done much research as this is one of the simplest things to do in CSS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 1):

You need to style your section like this:

```
#video {
  background-image: url("images/image_name.jpg");
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEWdBM)